# Office 2013 Click to Run - Primary Interop Assemblies

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, powershell

Given that the Office 2013 click-to-run installer allows no customisation of the installation, whatsoever, how can I install, or where can I find an installer for the Primary Interop Assemblies/.NET assemblies?

**Other info:**

This problem is inherent because I am using a PowerShell script that utilises Word Interop assemblies. It works under Office 2010 installs, but wiith Office 2013 I get an error. From research, it looks as though I need to install the Office 2013 PIAs, but cannot find how to do so.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to get a non-click-to-run version of Word/Office.

From MS's [Configuring a Computer to Develop Office Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx):

> **Note:** Visual Studio 2012 does not support creating Office solutions when the development computer has a version of Office 2013 or Microsoft Office 2010 that was delivered by means of Click-to-Run.

Also, as you've probably found, when you try to ["Change" the Office install and add the PIAs](http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Office%202013%20Primary%20Interop%20Assemblies) via Add/Remove Programs, the Click-To-Run version doesn't give you the kind of options required to add features (just 'Repair', and 'Repair Online').

Currently you can download the [PIA's for 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) (and earlier) as a redistributable, but so far there's no separate redistributable for the 2013 PIAs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was my worst fear. I was hoping there was a workaround. As far as I can see, *ONLY* volume licensed customers can use MSI based installers. Would you happen to know anything to the contrary?

Comment: If you log onto your MS account that you used to register/install the Click-To-Run version you can download an .IMG file of the disk.  Not sure it's going to help any though.

Comment: Yes I was already aware of that, thanks. I had also tried to install the 2010 and 2007 PIA redists, but to no avail; still receiving the same error from the PowerShell script.